# Determine Which Event Triggers a Change of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently wrote a plugin but it is conflicting with my current client's WordPress setup.

I think I have the conflict narrowed down to a certain problem:

- when my plugin is active, the user cannot calculate the price of variation product

I have disabled the plugin so you can see the price calculation working.

https://tagvinduet.manguster.dk/produkt/test-product/ (password = test)

Select two options and the price is automatically generated.

My question is, how do I find out which event is causing this triggering this event?

I've searched the codebase but am struggling to find it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you enable it? so i can check it.

Comment: do you have an error in the console when the variation price doesn't appears ?

Comment: https://tagvinduet.manguster.dk/produkt/test-product-enabled/ enabled here, password=test

Comment: no errors I could report :(